# Force iframe to open link in parent, If domains are different

Tags: html, iframe

I have iframe to google.com, while my parent page is on my own website.
When I get search results I want the links from iframe (search results) when clicked, be opened on parent page, is it possible to do so?

Comment: https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-open-a-link-from-iframe-in-the-parent-window.html#:~:text=To%20open%20the%20link%20from,in%20the%20section.

Comment: @zer00ne, I thought the domains are same geds

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.